# python- constant dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, constants

I simply generate a list of python dictionaries, and then serialize it to json.
Basically my code is a loop where I do something like:

```
ls.append({..values..})
```

I don't change the dictionaries after this.

The question, is there a constant dictionary in python, obviously the point here is memory, since I know dictionary takes more memory than a list.  I simply need the structure of `{key:value}` for json,  not the other features of the dictionary.

Just curious if I can optimize my code a bit.

Comment: If it's never going to change, and you're only going to use it in JSON form, you could just convert it to JSON and then save that in a string.

Comment: Why do you imagine that an immutable dictionary (if one existed) would consume less memory than mutable one?

Comment: Python does not have constants

Comment: @Robᵩ  simple, because dictionary takes a lot of space for the hash table.

Comment: So you don't need the hash table? That is, you're willing to live with O(n) lookup time?

Comment: @Robᵩ That's what I'm trying to say, I don't need looking in the dictionaries after I create it and append them to the list. I just need the {key:value} structure for outputiing to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

At its core, JSON is just a standardized way of converting more complex structures into plain text, in a way that any JSON-compatible application would understand. Because of this, the most time- and memory-efficient way of storing a non-changing, JSON-used object is to convert it to its JSON text form and store it in a string. That not only saves you from storing dictionaries in memory, but you don't need to do any more JSON conversions after that. You can just output that string to whatever application needs to receive the JSON object.

```
>>> import json
>>> testdict = {}
>>> testdict["pooh bear"] = "honey tree"
>>> jsonstr = json.dumps(testdict)
>>> jsonstr
'{"pooh bear": "honey tree"}'
```

As the comments have pointed out, Python does not have constants, nor does it have a more memory-constrained dictionary to my knowledge. The dictionary is implemented as a hash table, which is designed for very quick inserts and accesses; whenever you have a really fast data structure, your tradeoff is usually that it takes up a lot of memory. This is a persistent thing in most any data structure you can think of.

Comment: I could do that. Though, I'm not sure what the output would be. Today I do the json.dump(list,response) after I've finished with my list of dictionaries. I think that if I'll do it this way, I'll have a list of strings, not sure if it will not be accepted by javascript.

Comment: json.dumps just outputs a string. If you have to assemble many dictionaries into one JSON object, it can be a little tricky to do manually without dumps, but it can be done.

Comment: Might want to consider updating your example data!

Comment: @joe_04_04 good point. Went with something a bit safer.